# width: 100% not working on div inside a div with display: table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a header for my div structure behaving as a table. The `<div class="table-header">` must be inside the `<section>`.

For some reason, the `<div class="table-header">`'s width: 100% doesn't work. Apparently because its parent has "display: table". Setting its parent to width: 100% doesn't help either.

I have tried setting "display: table-header-group" with the same luck.

You can find a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xvr1otxs/21/

HTML

```
<section class="table">
    <div class="table-header"><div>header<a>weee</a></div></div>
    <article class="table-row">
        <div>
            <p>a</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>b</p>
        </div>
        <div class="small first">
            <p>c</p>
        </div>
        <div class="small last">
            <p>d</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>e</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>f</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

CSS

```
 *{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;}
 *{margin:0;padding:0;}
 html,body{width:100%;height:100%;}
 body{font-size:12pt;line-height:1;letter-spacing:0;font-family:Arial;}

 .table-header{display: table-header-group;}
 .table{display:table;table-layout:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;}
 .table-row{display:table-row;}
 .table-row>*{display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;}
 .table-row>*:nth-child(odd){background:tomato;}
 .table-row>*:nth-child(even){background:lightblue;}
 .table-row>.small{display:inline-block;width:100%;height:100%;}
 .table-row>.small.first{height:100px;overflow-y:scroll;}
 .table-row>.small.last{height:calc(100% - 100px);}
 a{float:right;}
 .table-header, .table-header div{width:100%;}
```

Comment: `display: table-caption;` http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/xvr1otxs/23/

Comment: works, thanks :)) post it as an answer if you wish, i'll accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your `.table-header` display to `table-caption`:

```
.table-header {
    display: table-caption;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/xvr1otxs/23/)

Answer (score 2):

That's because your div.table-header must have the same number of columns as div.table-row. You can't merge multiple columns like the colspan attribute does when using css tables. So a solution would be to use a table instead.